Geometry Nodes: How move parent objects and its children to world center position (0,0,0)?
Is there a way to move any object "back" to the world scene center by using the "set position" node?
For example: reset an object world position bevor using it as an instance source.
My goal: I want to distribute some objects inside a collection that all contain parented children objects.
Or is there another way? The problem is: the parent object, that have to be used as instance, is not placed in the world center so the position is shifted!



The problem here is that you do not use Separate Children (and "children" are in this case objects in the collection). As long as they are not separated (and treated as individuals), Blender keeps them in their offset position to make sure their relative position to each other stays intact (otherwise they would be treated separately, which is disabled). Usually enabling Separate Children to make it work is not a problem, but in your case you have 4 objects which you want to be treated as two objects. But Separate Children does not respect the parent-child relation of the base objects.

Thank you Gordon. I know this, but asked myself if there's a solution to keep the hierarchy and use the parents with their children as seperate instances.

The (probably) only way to accomplish this is to first place the objects that are to be added as children with Geometry Nodes, and then to instantiate the parent elements as usual.
The problem here is that although the Collection Info node can reset the positions of the contained objects with Separate Children and Reset Children, the reset always refers to all objects. This also includes those objects that have been added as children.
You can therefore easily solve this with the following setup:

First add the children to the parent objects with their own Geometry Nodes modifier.
Then instantiate these objects and make sure that Pick Instance is activated.
(Blender 4.1.1+)

Thank you. Interesting way, but actually not the solution I expected. I think its basically not possible, (yet). No one would do it this way. I hope some day it will be possible to distribute parent models and all children objects will be automatically taken into account.

@ChristophWerner Yes, this may change in future versions, which would be nice, but I don't think there is any other solution at the moment.
